# How to define interface for methods on struct pointer

Tags: go, go-interface

For `struct`s, it is possible to define a `func` that can update `struct` variables. Is there any way to use those functions in `interface`?

In the following code, I tried to create a minimal example to describe my question. two `struct` of `Rect` and `Circle` are defined. Both of the `struct`s have `Perimeter` and `Expand` functions.
`Perimeter` function calculates the perimeter of the shape. `Expand` function increases the perimeter of the shape by changing its properties. Also `Shape` interface with the `Perimeter` method signature is defined.

`viewShapeData` function accept input parameter of `Shape` type. This function view data of the shapes and also run the `Perimeter` method and view the perimeter of shapes.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Shape interface {
    Perimeter() float64
}

type Rect struct {
    width  float64
    height float64
}

type Circle struct {
    radius float64
}

func (s Rect) Perimeter() float64 {
    return 2 * (s.width + s.height)
}

func (s Circle) Perimeter() float64 {
    return 2 * 3.14 * s.radius
}

func (s *Rect) Expand(increaseValue float64) {
    s.width += increaseValue / 2
}

func (s *Circle) Expand(increaseValue float64) {
    s.radius += increaseValue / 3.14 / 2
}

func main() {
    a := Circle{radius: 10.0}
    b := Rect{width: 2.4, height: 5}

    a.Expand(1)
    viewShapeData(a)

    b.Expand(1)
    viewShapeData(b)
}

func viewShapeData(s Shape) {
    fmt.Printf("value: %v, Type: %T, Perimeter: %f\n", s, s, s.Perimeter())
}
```

Now I'm looking for a way to call the `Expand` method in the `viewShapeData` function. I tried different ways and applied the following changes in the described code:

```
type Shape interface {
    Perimeter() float64
    Expand(float64)
}

func main() {
    a := Circle{radius: 10.0}
    b := Rect{width: 2.4, height: 5}

    viewShapeData(a)
    viewShapeData(b)
}

func viewShapeData(s Shape) {
    s.Expand(1)
    fmt.Printf("value: %v, Type: %T, Perimeter: %f\n", s, s, s.Perimeter())
}
```

But these errors appear:

```
cannot use a (type Circle) as type Shape in argument to viewShapeData:
        Circle does not implement Shape (Expand method has pointer receiver)
cannot use b (type Rect) as type Shape in argument to viewShapeData:
        Rect does not implement Shape (Expand method has pointer receiver)
```

Please give me a solution or tell me why Golang does not support this kind of coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to use a pointer receiver, you also should pass a pointer into the function that takes the interface.

For example

```golang
func main() {
    a := Circle{radius: 10.0}
    b := Rect{width: 2.4, height: 5}
    
    a.Expand(1)
    viewShapeData(&a)

    b.Expand(1)
    viewShapeData(&b)
}
```

https://play.golang.com/p/pmHd5yl_v8p